# What's the top-left Button in KDE Windows?

Tags: kde, window-manager

I run Linux Mint 15 with KDE 4+.

Consider this screenshot:

[image]

Underneath the LM logo, or beside the Firefox icon, above "File" and "Edit", there's a little circular button with a dot in the middle. I don't know what it does, and haven't been able to figure it out yet. Can anyone tell me what it does?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That dot is to stick window visible on all workspaces.

Comment: Why did I start seeing such button only now??